# Unreliable and extreme delay monitoring Service status

Tags: c#, delay, monitoring, servicecontroller

Im currently developing a program in C#, that monitors the status of services, running on a server. I'm using **System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController**'s **waitforstatus** funktion. The Problem is, if I run my program as an Consol-Program, everything works fine and the program detects status changes nearly in realtime. But if I run it as a Windows Service, it works very unreliable and delayed. Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Here the code (it runs in a seperated thread):

```
        while (true)
        {
            lock (_myService)
            {
                _myService.Refresh();

                if (_myState == ServiceState.running)
                    _myService.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
                else if (_myState == ServiceState.stopped)
                    _myService.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);

                if (_myService.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                    _myState = ServiceState.running;
                if (_myService.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
                    _myState = ServiceState.stopped;

                stateChanged?.Invoke(this, new ServiceStateChangeEventArgs(_name, _myState));
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are burning  a lot of cpu cycles there but WaitForStatus will only detect changes once every 250 ms. So instead of the while loop, use a timer that runs every 250 ms for starters